# How to rotate a bufferedimage, then copy the bufferedImage into a pixel array

Tags: java, image, awt, java-2d, affinetransform

I am  trying to rotate a bufferedImage of a missile turret so that it looks like it's following a target. Basically, I can do it easily with the AffineTransform/ affinetransform

my current code in a nutshell is:

```
public BufferedImage tower = null;

try
        {
            tower = ImageIO.read(SpriteSheet.class.getResource("/spriteSheet/testTower.png"));
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {


AffineTransform tx = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(rotationRequired, locationX, locationY);
AffineTransformOp = op = new AffineTransformOp(tx, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);

//then I draw it using  

g.drawImage(op.filter(tower, null), towerLocationX, towerLocationY, null);
```

this works, but what I want to do is transform(rotate) the bufferedImage, then copy the newly rotated pixel data into a pixel array and then draw it onto the screen because I believe this is how most games draw rotating images as opposed to drawing a png directly to the screen.

But what do I know. How exactly do 2D games draw rotating images? Am I doing it correctly, or is there a better/ more memory efficient way of doing this?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Done. The class is called trigTester. http://pastebin.com/Di1WbMjr  . You can ignore all the math. That's just for calculating the rotation radian. The only code you need to look at are at render(), tick(), and the constructor(). I am not sure if I made my question clear. Basically I want to know if it's possible do the rotation directly to the pixel array containing the pixel information for the tower.png, then copying that pixel data onto the main screen pixel array to draw it, as opposed to drawing it onto the screen directly as png.

Comment: *"You can ignore all the math."*  I generally ignore links.  If the code is an SSCCE, add it as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15313836/edit).

Comment: @GayLord: if you want strangers to put the effort into understanding your problem and helping you, it will greatly help and would be greatly appreciated if you put the effort into making it easier to help you. I second Andrew's recommendation that you create an [sscce](http://sscce.org) here as an edit to your question.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to tackle image manipulation in 2D games. Before optimizing though, you should ask yourself if there's a real need for it to begin with. Moreover, memory optimization usually comes at the cost of CPU performance and vice verse.

If CPU time is the problem, a common approach is to keep an array of images already rotated to certain angles (precalculated).

If memory is the problem, keep a single image and calculate the rotated form each time it's displayed. An even more memory efficient yet CPU consuming approach, is to draw vector shapes rather than images. This also leads to better looking results than the interpolation of the smoothing algorithm used for images when transformed. Java supports SVG, and there are several good packages available (e.g. http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/).

Finally, Java can be connected to graphic libraries in order to perform the rendering, thus improving performance. Such libraries (OpenGL, etc.) use the memory of the graphic cards to store images in order to improve CPU usage (http://jogamp.org/jogl/www/).